# Timing belt. Crankshaft and camshaft pin holes don't meet. How do I get them to meet?

Tags: ford, timing-belt, galaxy

FORD GALAXY 2.0 TDCI WA6 GHIA. I put a new timing belt on without a problem but a warning engine light started showing. I was told on a forum that it was probably because one of the teeth was out of sync. I decided to re-do the timing belt. So I'm in the middle of doing it right now and the problem is that the Crankshaft dead point hole doesn't align with Camshaft dead point hole.I removed the starter but every time I did either the crankshaft or camshaft the camshaft is at 10 o'clock an the camshaft is at 3o'clock.

Can I just turn the Camshaft to 3.00 pm manually; or should I do that with the crankshaft?
HELP
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Images of what you're doing here would go a long way :o)

Comment: Are you aware top dead center for timing four stroke engines requires 720 degrees of crankshaft rotation (crankshaft rotated two times) before TDC is achieved for timing alignment? Using a straw or long screwdriver inserted into cylinder #1 while observing intake and exhaust valves close as the crankshaft timing marks align should help to align the camshaft. Remember, crankshaft at tdc then aligh camshaft timing marks.